# Checkbox in VB6.0 with multiple forms

Tags: vb6

I'm still beginner in programming pls understand me..I have two forms namely "form1" and "form2"...I have this code in my "form1"

```
Private Sub chkRegisteredLocation_Click()

If checkbox1.value = 1 Then
   datacombo1.Enabled = True
Else
    checkbox1.Enabled = False
    datacombo1.Text = ""

End If
End Sub
```

Now in my "form2" how do I know if my checkbox1 is True or Checked?

Comment: is the form2 opened by e.g. a button in form1 ? 
In which relation are the forms ? can you maybe attach a picture to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved...

```
public blnCheckbox as Boolean

Private Sub chkRegisteredLocation_Click()

If checkbox1.value = 1 Then
blnCheckbox = True
datacombo1.Enabled = True
Else
checkbox1.Enabled = False
datacombo1.Text = ""

End If
End Sub
```

Form2

```
If form1.blnCheckbox = True Then
msgbox("Checked")
end If
```